# How can I manually set the document id in a corpus?

Tags: r, tm

I am creating a Copus from a dataframe. I pass it as a `VectorSource` as there is only one column I want to be used as the text source. This works find however I need the document ids within the corpus to match the document ids from the dataframe. The document ids are stored in a separate column in the original dataframe.

```
df <- as.data.frame(t(rbind(c(1,3,5,7,8,10), 
                        c("text", "lots of text", "too much text", "where will it end",         "give peas a chance","help"))))
colnames(df) <- c("ids","textColumn")
library("tm")
library("lsa")
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(df[["textColumn"]]))
```

Running this code creates a corpus however the document ids run from 1-6. Is there any way of creating the corpus with the document ids 1,3,5,7,8,10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one simple but not very elegant way to assign your ids to your documents afterward could be the following :

```
for (i in 1:length(corpus)) {
   attr(corpus[[i]], "ID") <- df$ids[i]
}
```

Comment: It works! I will wait a bit to see if anyone can come up with something more elegant, perhaps assigning them during the actual corpus creation. But if they cant I'll gladly accept this, if not for your speed of answer alone ;)

Comment: @user1098798 Thanks ! I slghtly modified my answer, because obviously you can directly reuse the ids from your original data...

Answer (score 5):

I know it's probably late for @user1098798, but there is a way how you can specify ids directly when creating the corpus. You need to load the data as `DataframeSource()` and add mapping to the columns:

```
corpus = VCorpus(DataframeSource(df), readerControl = list(reader = readTabular(mapping = list(content = "textColumn", id = "ids"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **qdap** approach to this problem that can handle it without the loop:

Use [qdap version >= 1.1.0](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/qdap-1-1-0-released-on-cran/) right from the get go to convert the dataframe to a `Corpus` and the ID tags will be automatically added.

```
with(df, as.Corpus(textColumn, ids))

## <<VCorpus>>
## Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 3
## Content:  documents: 6


## Look around a bit
meta(with(df, as.Corpus(textColumn, ids)), tag="id")
inspect(with(df, as.Corpus(textColumn, ids)))
```

Comment: `df2tm_corpus` is deprecated; can you edit your answer and replace it with `as.Corpus` instead?

Comment: this doesnt work !, i always have null values int he results