# How to combine a DTM to its original Data Frame with less deleted tweets/documents?

Tags: r, twitter, corpus, tweets

So I am building a framework for my research on tweets. Part of my framework includes building the final dataset to be used for classification and topics modelling purposes later on.

I have three objects:
1.) ngram.features.df - contains 44159 rows/tweets, 3 columns namely, ID, X1 and X2
2.) tweets.corpus - corpus created from the ngram.features.df column X1, X1 contains the cleaned tweet for processing
3.) mydtm - is a document term matrix reduced down to 44043 rows/tweets because I have eliminated rows/tweets with doc.lengths = 0. This was done through:
`doc.lengths <- rowSums(as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(tweets.corpus))) 
mydtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(tweets.corpus[doc.lengths > 0], control = list(wordLengths = c(3,10)))`

`> mydtm
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 44043, terms: 9252)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 325412/407160424
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 10
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)`

As you can see, `mydtm` is down to `44043` rows while my original dataframe `ngram.features.df` where mydtm was built from had `44159` rows.

Now, I could not retain the `ID's` of the original documents/tweets from the dataframe into the `mydtm`.

I tried the one in [How can I manually set the document id in a corpus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852357/how-can-i-manually-set-the-document-id-in-a-corpus/14852502#14852502) but it pertains to setting IDs inside a corpus not on the DTM.

The problem now lies with `merge`. I will `merge` `ngram.features.df` (44159) with a data frame version of `mydtm` (44043). However, they would have inconsistent number of rows/tweets/documents here due to the reduction. Thus, the need to retain IDs.

Anyone who can provide assistance?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is after you removed the empty documents from your `dtm` is create a data.frame and creating a new column with the `rownames` of the `dtm`. Then you can merge this data.frame with your ngram.features.df data.frame

```
mydtm_as_df <- data.frame(docs = rownames(as.matrix(mydtm )), as.matrix(mydtm ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi! I will try this now. Thanks for the help!